# Collapse all groups in each sheet via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have en Excel file containing of different sheets. Each sheet has `groups` both in **Columns** and **Rows**.

Now I want to have a VBA that goes through each sheet and collapses the groups.

Therefore, I programmed the below code:

```
Sub Collapse()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        ActiveWindow.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1
        ActiveWindow.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    Next b
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, for this code I get a runtime error 438.

Do you have any idea what I need to modify in my VBA to collapse all groups in each sheet?

Comment: replace `ActiveWindow` by `b`. If this doesn't help please provide the exact error massage and in which line the error occurs. Also you can do this in one command only: `b.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1, ColumnLevels:=1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply substitute `ActiveWindow` with `b`, like this and it will work:

```
Sub Collapse()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        b.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1
        b.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    Next b
End Sub
```

**Edit #1**

Shorter version, cf. `PEH`'s comment:

```
Sub Collapse()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        b.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1, RowLevels:=1
    Next b
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: one command is enough: `b.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1, ColumnLevels:=1`. Should be faster.